# Combined variance following multiple imputation with survival model

Tags: r, variance, survival, multiple-imputation

I have created 5 imputations of a dataset and have fit a survival model to them all in R. I want to combine the estimates of the coefficients and the standard errors of the coefficients. To do this I have taken the mean of the coefficients and combined the standard errors using Rubins formula, i.e. 
$$(1+1/m) \times \text{between imputation variance} + \text{within imputation variance}$$

I was thinking about it and I'm having some doubts as to whether this makes sense? Wouldn't the variance be over estimated in this case? I performed a t-test on the coefficients and it results in a relatively high p-value when I know the data should show a good correlation. I use Rubins df formula for the t-test. Is there an alternative method of producing the combine variance, one that doesn't result in over estimation?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you think Rubin's variance estimator is biased upwards? In certain situations (e.g. the imputer assumes less than the analyst, see http://www.stat.harvard.edu/Faculty_Content/meng/StatSci94.pdf) it can be biased upwards, but in these cases multiple imputation is often still the most practical approach to handling missingness. The preceding paper gives a careful analysis of the conditions under which Rubin's variance estimator is unbiased, and when it overestimates the variance.